# Full calendar angular

Tags: angular, date, fullcalendar

I am using full calendar in angular, when I click on some date in current month , I want to highlight the same date in next month, how can I achieve it?

I am not getting any parameters in next month to highlight the selected date

Comment: What View are you using when you want to do this? Is it one of the multi-month views? Or timeline? Or what? You're right there is no specific function to do this in fullcalendar, but depending on the view, it _might_ be possible to write some custom JS to do it

Comment: I m using single month calendar, and when clicking on next month button, it displays next month calendar, but selected date or current date is not coming in highlight colour

Comment: Do you mean if, for example, if you have a view of February 2024 and the grid is also showing 2nd March at the end, and you wrote some code to "select" 2nd March, then when the view moves to March, you want 2nd March to still be selected? You'll have to have some custom code to remember what was selected, and re-select it, in that case, because moving the view to a new month causes all the HTML to be re-rendered, and fullCalendar doesn't remember what was there before.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesSet can be used to detect when the date range has changed, but in terms of remembering what date you had clicked on and selected previously, you will need to implement your own code to remember that state.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I m  having selected date or date clicked ,  but how can I highlight or add class on that day in next month?

Comment: Well if you want to re-create a selection, run https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-select . As far as I know there's no fullcalendar API method for simulating a click on an event, but if you can find the right DOM element you could fire its "click" function directly.

Comment: No problem. If you think your solution might help others in future, please post the code as an Answer below - see also [answer].